# Is it safe to enable safe boot on Windows as long as I don't boot into Ubuntu?

Tags: dual-boot, windows-10

I have Windows 10 and Ubuntu 15.10 (if I'm not mistaken) in my laptop, but I usually use Windows 10. Because of that I set Windows Boot Manager to default and when I want to boot into Ubuntu, I press F12, select GRUB and Ubuntu.

But, unfortunately, because fast boot is disabled (to avoid data loss), Windows takes too much time to boot, unless I make it hibernate.

Even though Ubuntu seems to fail to boot when I set fast boot on or hibernate Windows (didn't do those on purpose) I still don't fell 100% safe to enable fast boot.

Would it be safe to enable fast boot when I'm not going to use Ubuntu (it's very hard to accidentally boot into Ubuntu now), and then turn it back off when I intend to use it?

Comment: You can even boot into Ubuntu with safe boot active. What you are NOT allowed to do is change anything to any Windows partitions. On reboot any of those changes will be -gone- due to the hiberfile being used to "restore" your system.

Comment: @Rinzwind Yeah, I actually know that, but since I rely on two shared NTFS partitions (one for Steam games and other for code), it would be useless to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is absolutely safe to enable hibernation and fast boot, it is more a matter of convenience.

Fast startup has to be enabled and disabled in the Windows Control Panel - Power Settings.

To enable hibernation - open command prompt as administrator and execute :

```
powercfg /h on
```

When you want to boot and use Ubuntu ... you have to disable it by executing :

```
powercfg /h off
```

Afterwards you have to **shutdown - NOT restart - the computer completely**.

Comment: Okay, thanks. But could you explain why shoud I disable hibernation and also why should I shutdown instead of restarting? I've always disabled only fast boot when I wanted to boot into Ubuntu.

Comment: @LHLaurini : You're welcome ! When you do not disable hibernation and  just reboot, the computer starts directly into Windows, so when you want to use Ubuntu, you have to disable it and shutdown completely. Maybe when you disable fast boot, hibernation will be disabled automatically, enjoy ubuntu experience ! :)

Comment: Actually, even if I don't disable hibernation (but of course not use it) and restart Windows I'm able to press F12 and open GRUB. I guess that behavior is different for each computer. Thank you so much.